# WCF Client with both Basic and Client Certificate Authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate, basic-authentication, ssl-client-authentication

I am trying to integrate with a Web Service end point which require Basic and Client Certificate for authentication using WCF. I tried below different setting based on suggestions online but still I am receiving  "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority XXXXX". Server uses well known CA which is already available in Windows Certificate Store. In code I am adding ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName , ClientCredentials.UserName.Password & ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate successfully.

1)

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
 </security>
```

Result : "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority XXXXX"

2)

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
     <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
 </security>
```

Result : Result : "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority XXXXX"

3)

```
<security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
             <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
  </security>
```

Result : The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="Realm"'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

How to attach the Client Certificate using Basic Authentication since the server is expecting Basic authentication based on error returned when setting clientCredentialType as "Certificate".

Note: Using SOAPUI I can successfully connect with server

Comment: See codeprojects : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429144/Simple-Instant-Messenger-with-SSL-Encryption-in-Cs

Comment: Thank you for your response but how this article is related to my query?

Comment: Just showing a working example of SSL.  If you are successful with SOAPUI I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare SOAPUI results with you app.  Usually adding missing http header will fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced  2.0 Web Service Reference instead of a WCF Service Reference to send request with both Basic &Client Authentication and it worked as expected.

Note : Web Reference is old style deprecated model.